# Can the WebScarab Tool intercept any HTTP request anywhere?

Tags: security, web-applications

Of late I have been diving deep into web application security. While browsing I found WebScarab Tool from OWASP which can inject possible attack in to your web application and make your application vulnerable.

I am using that tool to intercept any request which goes through my web application based on JSF 1.2 Framework. While using I observed that whatever values are entered in form fields are shown as it is HttpRequest in this tool.You can modify these values and it will automatically create a new request header and strikingly the modified values will be inserted into the DB.

Isn't it a potential attack? I mean anyone can intercept any HttpRequest and modify the parameter with the help of a tool and inject some malicious content,

My questions are:

1. Is it possible for everyone to intercept HttpRequest generating from any webpage, say stackoverflow.com?
2. If yes, how can you avoid these modification by an unknown user who can modify the parameter and remake the encoded URL?
3. If no, please explain why? I am absolutely numb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WebScarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project) is a proxy:

> WebScarab operates as an intercepting proxy, allowing the operator to review and modify requests created by the browser before they are sent to the server, and to review and modify responses returned from the server before they are received by the browser.

But this requires the client (e.g. your web browser) to actually [use the proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/WebScarab_Getting_Started):

> In order to start using WebScarab as a proxy, you need to configure your browser to use WebScarab as a proxy. This is configured in IE using the Tools menu. Select Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings to get the proxy configuration dialog.

So only the communication of clients that use the WebScarab proxy can be intercepted.

Answer (score 0):

Using WebScarab or other UI Interceptor tool, person can Change the Transaction data in between of processing of request from Client to Server.

Basically this can be avoided by applying Same Validations at both Client and Server side of the application.
eg, if Application has Change pwd functionality, and someone tries Interceptor and modifies the pwd with new intercepted Pwd., while saving it should be validated on server side , whether user entered correct password or not.